# How to install cryptography on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, cryptography, pip

My OS: Mac OS X El Capitan

When I install cryptography like this:

```
pip install cryptography==0.2.1
```

The error was:

```
Collecting cryptography==0.2.1
  Using cached cryptography-0.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    six: module references __path__

    Installed /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
    Searching for cffi>=0.8
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
    Best match: cffi 1.5.0
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=dec8441e67880494ee881305059af656
    Processing cffi-1.5.0.tar.gz
    Writing /var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/easy_install-ZAtQYR/cffi-1.5.0/setup.cfg
    Running cffi-1.5.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/easy_install-ZAtQYR/cffi-1.5.0/egg-dist-tmp-Dl08xt
    creating /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg
    Extracting cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg to /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs

    Installed /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg
    Searching for pycparser
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
    Best match: pycparser 2.14
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.14.tar.gz#md5=a2bc8d28c923b4fe2b2c3b4b51a4f935
    Processing pycparser-2.14.tar.gz
    Writing /var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/easy_install-80l9Lo/pycparser-2.14/setup.cfg
    Running pycparser-2.14/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/easy_install-80l9Lo/pycparser-2.14/egg-dist-tmp-5dC3Ib
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    Copying pycparser-2.14-py2.7.egg to /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs

    Installed /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/pycparser-2.14-py2.7.egg
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_cffi__xfdb41ad9xb4fc9075.c:369:5: error: conflicting types for 'ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME_check'
    int ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME_check(ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME *);
        ^
    /usr/local/include/openssl/asn1.h:856:5: note: previous declaration is here
    int ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME_check(const ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME *a);
        ^
    1 error generated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/setup.py", line 113, in <module>
        "build": cffi_build,
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 180, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 291, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 118, in add_defaults
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 28, in finalize_options
        orig.build_py.finalize_options(self)
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_py.py", line 46, in finalize_options
        ('force', 'force'))
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 298, in set_undefined_options
        src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/setup.py", line 55, in finalize_options
        OpenSSLBinding().ffi.verifier.get_extension(),
      File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 83, in __init__
        self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
      File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 99, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
        libraries)
      File "cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 72, in build_ffi
        ext_package="cryptography",
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 433, in verify
        lib = self.verifier.load_library()
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/verifier.py", line 110, in load_library
        self._compile_module()
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/verifier.py", line 207, in _compile_module
        outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 29, in compile
        outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose)
      File "/private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 62, in _build
        raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
    cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/48/lrr_y58s4rq70qdnjcvqc8l8j2g31b/T/pip-build-zGO9s0/cryptography
```

I am sure that I have upgrade the `openssl` to the newest version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
```

But I don't know how to fix it. Even I checked the official documentation:

> https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-os-x

And follow that to do, the result was the same.

Comment: Are you sure your Python packaging toolchain is up-to-date?  When I install cryptography using pip in El Capitan, it simply downloads and installs a .whl (binary) package.  Which versions of pip and setuptools are you using?

Comment: pip: 8.0.2; setuptools 18.2.

Comment: I just created a new, blank virtualenv and tried to install cryptography 0.2.1 in there… and I got the same error.  (Installing the latest version 1.2.2 works flawlessly.  I assume you have a good reason for wanting the old version?)  I’m going to work through the error now to see if I can get to the bottom of it…

Comment: In any event, the problem is due to the fact that the OpenSSL headers (though not the library itself) have been removed from El Capitan as part of Apple’s ongoing (since 10.7) deprecation of OpenSSL in favour of their own Cryptographic Services.  In theory one should be able to build these Python modules against a version of OpenSSL installed by (say) Homebrew.  I’m trying — and thus far failing — to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My project using the cryptography 0.2.1 for a long time. We didn't upgrade it yet. I think you are right. The problem is OpenSSL and the Mac OS X.

Answer (score 14):

`brew` to the rescue:

```
brew install openssl
```

then `brew` gives a hint:

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

So just export these env vars and rerun your favorite pip install (or better to avoid havoc in future add following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

This worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Trying to install the [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) I need to install cryptography package on Mac OS El Capitan. As explained in [Cryptography installation doc](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/)

```
env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography
```

Answer (score -2):

I had tried just about everything on this but still kept getting the following error:
   ...    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:5258:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return BIO_do_handshake(bio);
        ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/bio.h:502:34: note: expanded from macro 'BIO_do_handshake'
    # define BIO_do_handshake(b)     BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_C_DO_STATE_MACHINE,0,NULL)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:7640:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_C_SET_SSL, flag, (char *)ssl);
        ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:7699:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                err = ERR_get_error();
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:7751:59: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            ms = ((start->tv_sec + (int)timeout) - tv.tv_sec) * 1000;
               ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:7996:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                err = ERR_get_error();
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8026:37: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        r = SSL_write(ssl, buf.buf, buf.len);
            ~~~~~~~~~               ~~~~^~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8069:37: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        r = SSL_write(ssl, buf.buf, buf.len);
            ~~~~~~~~~               ~~~~^~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8087:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                err = ERR_get_error();
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8143:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, mode);
        ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:2484:9: note: expanded from macro 'SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode'
            SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx,SSL_CTRL_SET_SESS_CACHE_MODE,m,NULL)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8148:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return SSL_CTX_get_session_cache_mode(ctx);
        ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:2486:9: note: expanded from macro 'SSL_CTX_get_session_cache_mode'
            SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx,SSL_CTRL_GET_SESS_CACHE_MODE,0,NULL)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8680:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        outlen = BIO_ctrl_pending(bio);
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:8742:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        outlen = BIO_ctrl_pending(bio);
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:22694:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          arg4 = len;
               ~ ^~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:25282:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          arg3 = len;
               ~ ^~~
    21 warnings generated.
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:2894:9: warning: variable 'res' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is true [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
        if (PyType_Ready(tp) < 0)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:2918:10: note: uninitialized use occurs here
      return res;
             ^~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:2894:5: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always false
        if (PyType_Ready(tp) < 0)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:2875:10: note: initialize the variable 'res' to silence this warning
      int res;
             ^
              = 0
    1 warning generated.
    cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include build/temp.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.o -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/M2Crypto/_m2crypto.so
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto': Permission denied

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/q5/qk1gf6z15kschmf5dwb3mqvh0000gn/T/pip-build-WyOs_y/M2crypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/q5/qk1gf6z15kschmf5dwb3mqvh0000gn/T/pip-tp6pQY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q5/qk1gf6z15kschmf5dwb3mqvh0000gn/T/pip-build-WyOs_y/M2crypto/

I had the hardest time getting it working. The fix ended up being a simple chmod as sudo:
sudo chmod 777 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Your answer is not readable. Please consider reformatting it after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).