# pip3 install cryptography MacOs gives error

Tags: python, django, macos, cryptography

the title says it all.

This is my error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/wy/9tlqy66d5630rd5htpz1dtnr0000gn/T/tmppjwpg3pg
       cwd: /private/var/folders/wy/9tlqy66d5630rd5htpz1dtnr0000gn/T/pip-install-cz6pcrd6/cryptography
  Complete output (52 lines):
  
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rust
  
      Python: 3.8.9
      platform: macOS-12.0.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
      pip: 20.2.3
      setuptools: 49.2.1
      setuptools_rust: 1.3.0
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 39, in <module>
      setup(
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in __init__
      _Distribution.__init__(self, {
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 293, in __init__
      self.finalize_options()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 721, in finalize_options
      ep(self)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 727, in _finalize_setup_keywords
      ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2483, in require
      items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 790, in resolve
      raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
  pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 49.2.1 (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=58.0'))
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/wy/9tlqy66d5630rd5htpz1dtnr0000gn/T/tmppjwpg3pg Check the logs for full command output.
```

Already tried the approach outlined here: [How to install cryptography on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147681/how-to-install-cryptography-on-mac-os-x)

with installing OpenSSL, just giving me the same error.

Appreciate any help

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package requires `setuptools` version 58.0 or greater to build. See output:

```
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 49.2.1 (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=58.0'))
```

Try `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` then retry the install.